# Show that eigenvalues are symmetric with respect to the origin

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

The matrices that I am considering are

$$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^\top
\end{bmatrix},
$$

with $A,B,C\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $C = C^\top$ and $B = B^\top$. I noticed from numerical calculations that the eigenvalues are symmetric with respect to the origin, i.e., if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ then $-\lambda$ is as well.

I have not been able to shown that this has to be the case. Initially I tried to see if I could come up with a similarity transformation which would make it block diagonal, with one block the negative of the other, but with no success. Next I tried to use some tricks to manipulate the determinant, namely I showed that

\begin{align}
\det(M - \lambda\,I) &= \det(B) \det((-A^\top - \lambda\,I) B^{-1} (A - \lambda\,I) - C) \\
&= \det(C) \det((A - \lambda\,I) C^{-1} (-A^\top - \lambda\,I) - B) \\
\end{align}

assuming that either $\det(B)\neq0$ or $\det(C)\neq0$. However, this did not seem to bring me any closer to showing that all eigenvalues are mirrored around the imaginary axis.

Comment: Are you sure you want to take transpose and not conjugated transpose? Also, the reflection of $\lambda$ to the imaginary axis is not $-\lambda$ but $-\bar\lambda$.

Comment: I have constructed a $8\times8$ matrix with the form of your matrix $M$ in Octave, and the eigenvalues are not mirrored around the imaginary axis, but if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue as well.

Comment: @Berci I did mean the normal transpose, but initially I did some test calculations using real matrices, which also have complex conjugate eigenvalues, so did not notice that it was actually a origin reflection instead of axis reflection. I also just figured out that my definition of $M$ is essentially the definition of an Hamiltonian matrix.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen:   I'd like to see how that works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of $M$ is the same as that of an [Hamiltonian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_matrix). In order to show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue as well, the following identity can be used

$$
\det(M - \lambda\,I) = \det(M^\top - \lambda\,I)
$$

Defining a new matrix as

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where it can be noted that $\det(J)=-1$ and $J^{-1} = J^\top = -J$. Using this matrix it can be shown that $J\,M^\top J = M$, namely

\begin{align}
J\,M^\top J &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^\top
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^\top & C \\
B & -A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
C & -A^\top \\
-A & -B
\end{bmatrix} \\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^\top
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Incorporating $J$ into the determinant from earlier allows use to show

\begin{align}
\det\left(J(M^\top - \lambda\,I)J\right) &= \det(J)^2\det\left(M^\top - \lambda\,I\right) = \det\left(M^\top - \lambda\,I\right) \\
&= \det\left(J\,M^\top J - \lambda\,J^2\right) \\
&= \det\left(M + \lambda\,I\right)
\end{align}

Therefore $\det\left(M - \lambda\,I\right) = \det\left(M + \lambda\,I\right)$. So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue $\det\left(M - \lambda\,I\right)$ is zero, but then $\det\left(M + \lambda\,I\right)$ would be zero as well and thus $-\lambda$ has to be an eigenvalue as well.